# Chrome Dev Tools - Connect Filesystem to Deployed

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug a project I'm running on my localhost with Chrome dev tools, and while that's possible from Sources > Page > Deployed > ... side-menu , I'd like to actually upload my entire project on the Filesystem page and have access to the entire project with JS and HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ! One is on your localhost, the other is simply a folder.